# How to convert String.getBtyes back to original String

Tags: java, encoding, decoding

I am encoding a string using the following method

```
public String encrypt(String data)
{             
        encoded = data.getBytes();
        String str_encoded = java.util.Arrays.toString(encoded);

        System.out.println("encoded:" + java.util.Arrays.toString(encoded));

        return str_encoded;
}
```

How do i decode the encoded string to get back my original string .

For example : "abc123" when encoded will be `[97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51]`

How do i decode `[97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51]` back into "abc123"

i am sure its quite simple , but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use below code. Create an `byte[]` and form the String.

```
String decoded = new String(new byte[]{97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51});
```

---

Complete code:

```
String[] bytes = str_encoded.substring(1, str_encoded.length() - 1).split(", ");

byte[] bytesArray = new byte[bytes.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytesArray.length; i++) {
    bytesArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(bytes[i]).byteValue();
}

String str_decoded = new String(bytesArray);
System.out.println(str_decoded);
```

Comment: The "{97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51}" is in string form , how do i convert it into byte array ??

Comment: remove enclosing brackets then split on the basis of comma and form the byte array.